# Python dictionary keys seem to vanish before I delete them

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm a newbie programmer working on an idea for a small game. I wanted my play space to be a grid for various reasons. Without a lot of good reason, I decided to create a class of GridSquare objects, each object having properties like size, an index to describe what (x,y) coordinates they represented, and some flags to determine if the grid squares were on land or empty space, for example. My grid is a dictionary of these objects, where each GridSquare is a key. The values in the dictionary are going to be various objects in the place space, so that I can easily look up which objects are on each grid square.

Just describing this I feel like a complete lunatic. Please bear in mind that I've only been at this a week.

My problem appears when I try to change the GridSquare objects. For example, I want to use a list to generate the land on each level. So I iterate over the list, and for each value I look through my grid squares using a for loop until I find one with the right index, and flip the GridSquare.land property. But I found that this caused a runtime error, since I was changing keys in a dictionary I was looping through. OK.

Now what I'm trying to do is to create a list of the keys I want to change. For each item in my level-generating list, I go through all the GridSquares in my grid dictionary until I find the one with the index I'm looking for, then I append that GridSquare to a list of old GridSquares that need updating. I then make another copy of the GridSquare, with some properties changed, in a list of altered GridSquares. Finally, I delete any keys from my grid dictionary which match my list of "old" GridSquares, and then add all of the altered ones into my grid dictionary.

The problem is that when I delete keys from my grid dictionary which match my list of "old" keys, I run into keyerrors. I can't understand what is happening to my keys before I can delete them. Using try/except, I can see that it's only a small number of the keys, which seems to vary kind of arbitrarily when I change parts of my code.

I would appreciate any insight into this behaviour.
Here is code for anyone still reading:

```py
aspect_ratio = (4, 3)
screen_size = (1280, 720)

#defining a class of objects called GridSquares
class GridSquare:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.index = (x, y)
        self.land = 0

#creates a dictionary of grid squares which I hope will function as a grid......
grid = {}
for x_index in range(1, (aspect_ratio[0] + 1)):
    for y_index in range (1, (aspect_ratio[1] + 1)):
        new_square = GridSquare(x_index, y_index)
        grid[new_square] = None

#these are lists to hold changes I need to make to the dictionary of grid squares
grid_changes = []
old_gridsquares = []

#this unweildly list is meant to be used to generate a level. Numbers represent land, spaces are empty space.
for number_no, number in enumerate(["1", "1", "1", "1",
                                    " ", " ", " ", " ",
                                    "1", "1", "1", "1"]):
                                    
    #makes grid squares land if they are designated as such in the list
    for gridsquare in grid.keys():
        #this if statement is meant to convert each letter's position in the list into an index like the grid squares have.
        if gridsquare.index == ((number_no + 1) % (aspect_ratio[0]), ((number_no + 1) // (aspect_ratio[0] + 1)) + 1):
            #create a list of squares that need to be updated, and a list of squares to be deleted
            old_gridsquares.append(gridsquare)
            flagged_gridsquare = GridSquare((number_no + 1) % (aspect_ratio[0]), ((number_no + 1) // (aspect_ratio[0] + 1)) + 1)
            flagged_gridsquare.land = 1
            #this part is meant to set the flag for the gridsquare that indicates if it is on the far side or the near side,
            #if it is land
            if number == "1":
                flagged_gridsquare.near = 1
            grid_changes.append(flagged_gridsquare)
#deletes from grid any items with a key that matches the old squares, and adds updated versions.
for old_gridsquare in old_gridsquares:
    try:
        del grid[old_gridsquare]
    except:
        print(old_gridsquare.index)
        print(old_gridsquare.land)
for grid_change in grid_changes:
    grid[grid_change] = None
```

Comment: tl;dr Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: keys dont vanish ... a dict is probably fine to store coordinates in general ... not quite as intuitive as a 2d array probably ... but not a problem either per say... you probably want to use copy.deepcopy to copy your dict ...